# Python - Append to CSV

Tags: python, append

I am trying to append to a CSV file with the following code

```
import csv
cat_options = [row for row in csv.reader(open('catOptions.csv', 'r'), delimiter =',')]
print cat_options
new_cat = raw_input("\nEnter the new category: ")
cat_options = csv.writer(open('catOptions.csv', 'a'))
cat_options = cat_options.writerows(new_cat)
```

Following is the output:
    "Housing"
    "Transportation"
    S
    a
    v
    i
    n
    g
    s

The file "catOptions.csv" has Housing and Transportation. I tried to append Savings and did not get the desired result. Each word appears on a separate line. However the following code gives me the desired result but i am curious to know if there is an efficient way to do this.

```
import csv
cat_options = [row for row in csv.reader(open('catOptions.csv', 'r'), delimiter =',')]
print cat_options
new_cat = []
new_cat.append(raw_input("\nEnter the new category: "))
cat_options = csv.writer(open('catOptions.csv', 'a'))
cat_options = cat_options.writerows([new_cat])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`csvwriter.writerow()`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) if you only want to write a single row.

Comment: However, you will still want to create a list, since a row consists of several items. The csv writer has no idea how many columns you want, so it expects you to pass an iterable. Strings are iterable, and get broken down into individual characters.

Comment: I tried it and following is the output
"Housing"
"Transportation"
"Savings"
"Health"
"Personal"
"Entertainment"
T,e,s,t

Karl, you are correct, i will need to use it as list.